# Convert quandl fx hourly data to daily

Tags: python, pandas, forex

I would like to convert hourly financial data imported into a pandas dataframe that has the following csv header to daily data:

```
symbol,date,hour,openbid,highbid,lowbid,closebid,openask,highask,lowask,closeask,totalticks
```

I've imported the data with pandas.read_csv(). I have eliminated all but one symbol from the data for testing purposes, and have figured out this part so far:

```
df.groupby('date').agg({'highask': [max], 'lowask': [min]})
```

I'm still pretty new to python, so I'm not really sure how to continue.  I'm guessing I can use some kind of anonymous function to create additional fields.  For example, I'd like to get the open ask price for each date at hour 0, and the close ask price for each data at hour 23.  Ideally, I would add additional columns and create a new dataframe.  I want add a new column for market price, that is a an average of the ask/bid for low, high, open, and close.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

*edit*

As requested, here is the output I would expect for just 2018-07-24:

```
symbol,date,openbid,highbid,lowbid,closebid,openask,highask,lowask,closeask,totalticks
AUD/USD,2018-07-24,0.7422,0.74297,0.7429,0.74196,0.74257,0.743,0.74197,0.74258,5191
```

openbid is the openbid at the lowest hour column for a single date, closebid is the closebid at the highest hour for a single date, etc.  Total ticks is the sum.  What I am really struggling with is determining openbid, openask, closebid, and closeask.

Sample data:

```
symbol,date,hour,openbid,highbid,lowbid,closebid,openask,highask,lowask,closeask,totalticks
AUD/USD,2018-07-24,22,0.7422,0.74249,0.74196,0.7423,0.74225,0.74252,0.74197,0.74234,1470
AUD/USD,2018-07-24,23,0.7423,0.74297,0.7423,0.74257,0.74234,0.743,0.74234,0.74258,3721
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,0,0.74257,0.74334,0.74237,0.74288,0.74258,0.74335,0.74239,0.74291,7443
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,1,0.74288,0.74492,0.74105,0.74111,0.74291,0.74501,0.74107,0.74111,14691
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,2,0.74111,0.74127,0.74015,0.74073,0.74111,0.74129,0.74018,0.74076,6898
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,3,0.74073,0.74076,0.73921,0.73987,0.74076,0.74077,0.73923,0.73989,6207
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,4,0.73987,0.74002,0.73921,0.73953,0.73989,0.74003,0.73923,0.73956,3453
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,5,0.73953,0.74094,0.73946,0.74041,0.73956,0.74096,0.73947,0.74042,7187
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,6,0.74041,0.74071,0.73921,0.74056,0.74042,0.74069,0.73922,0.74059,10646
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,7,0.74056,0.74066,0.73973,0.74035,0.74059,0.74068,0.73974,0.74037,9285
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,8,0.74035,0.74206,0.73996,0.74198,0.74037,0.74207,0.73998,0.742,10234
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,9,0.74198,0.74274,0.74176,0.74225,0.742,0.74275,0.74179,0.74227,8224
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,10,0.74225,0.74237,0.74122,0.74142,0.74227,0.74237,0.74124,0.74143,7143
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,11,0.74142,0.74176,0.74093,0.74152,0.74143,0.74176,0.74095,0.74152,7307
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,12,0.74152,0.74229,0.74078,0.74219,0.74152,0.74229,0.74079,0.74222,10523
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,13,0.74219,0.74329,0.74138,0.74141,0.74222,0.74332,0.74136,0.74145,13983
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,14,0.74141,0.74217,0.74032,0.74065,0.74145,0.7422,0.74034,0.74067,21814
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,15,0.74065,0.74151,0.73989,0.74113,0.74067,0.74152,0.73988,0.74115,16085
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,16,0.74113,0.74144,0.74056,0.7411,0.74115,0.74146,0.74058,0.74111,7752
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,17,0.7411,0.7435,0.74092,0.74346,0.74111,0.74353,0.74094,0.74348,11348
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,18,0.74346,0.74445,0.74331,0.74373,0.74348,0.74446,0.74333,0.74373,9898
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,19,0.74373,0.74643,0.74355,0.74559,0.74373,0.74643,0.74358,0.7456,11756
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,20,0.74559,0.74596,0.74478,0.74549,0.7456,0.746,0.74481,0.74562,5607
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,21,0.74549,0.74562,0.74417,0.74438,0.74562,0.74576,0.74422,0.74442,3613
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,22,0.73762,0.73792,0.73762,0.73774,0.73772,0.73798,0.73768,0.73779,1394
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,23,0.73774,0.73813,0.73744,0.73807,0.73779,0.73816,0.73746,0.73808,3465
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,0,0.73807,0.73826,0.73733,0.73763,0.73808,0.73828,0.73735,0.73764,6582
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,1,0.73763,0.73854,0.73734,0.73789,0.73764,0.73857,0.73736,0.73788,7373
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,2,0.73789,0.73881,0.73776,0.73881,0.73788,0.73883,0.73778,0.73882,3414
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,3,0.73881,0.7393,0.73849,0.73875,0.73882,0.73932,0.73851,0.73877,4639
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,4,0.73875,0.739,0.73852,0.73858,0.73877,0.73901,0.73852,0.73859,2487
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,5,0.73858,0.73896,0.7381,0.73887,0.73859,0.73896,0.73812,0.73888,5332
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,6,0.73887,0.73902,0.73792,0.73879,0.73888,0.73902,0.73793,0.73881,7623
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,7,0.73879,0.7395,0.73844,0.73885,0.73881,0.7395,0.73846,0.73887,9577
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,8,0.73885,0.73897,0.73701,0.73727,0.73887,0.73899,0.73702,0.73729,12280
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,9,0.73727,0.73784,0.737,0.73721,0.73729,0.73786,0.73701,0.73723,8634
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,10,0.73721,0.73798,0.73717,0.73777,0.73723,0.73798,0.73718,0.73779,7510
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,11,0.73777,0.73789,0.73728,0.73746,0.73779,0.73789,0.7373,0.73745,4947
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,12,0.73746,0.73927,0.73728,0.73888,0.73745,0.73929,0.73729,0.73891,16853
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,13,0.73888,0.74083,0.73853,0.74066,0.73891,0.74083,0.73855,0.74075,14412
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,14,0.74066,0.74147,0.74025,0.74062,0.74075,0.74148,0.74026,0.74064,15187
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,15,0.74062,0.74112,0.74002,0.74084,0.74064,0.74114,0.74003,0.74086,10044
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,16,0.74084,0.74091,0.73999,0.74001,0.74086,0.74092,0.74,0.74003,6893
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,17,0.74001,0.74022,0.73951,0.74008,0.74003,0.74025,0.73952,0.74009,5865
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,18,0.74008,0.74061,0.74002,0.74046,0.74009,0.74062,0.74004,0.74047,4334
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,19,0.74046,0.74072,0.74039,0.74041,0.74047,0.74073,0.74041,0.74043,3654
AUD/USD,2018-07-27,20,0.74041,0.74066,0.74005,0.74011,0.74043,0.74068,0.74018,0.74023,1547
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,22,0.74438,0.74526,0.74436,0.74489,0.74442,0.7453,0.74439,0.74494,2220
AUD/USD,2018-07-25,23,0.74489,0.74612,0.74489,0.7459,0.74494,0.74612,0.74492,0.74592,4886
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,0,0.7459,0.74625,0.74536,0.74571,0.74592,0.74623,0.74536,0.74573,6602
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,1,0.74571,0.74633,0.74472,0.74479,0.74573,0.74634,0.74471,0.74481,10123
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,2,0.74479,0.74485,0.74375,0.74434,0.74481,0.74487,0.74378,0.74437,7844
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,3,0.74434,0.74459,0.74324,0.744,0.74437,0.74461,0.74328,0.744,6037
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,4,0.744,0.74428,0.74378,0.74411,0.744,0.7443,0.74379,0.74414,3757
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,5,0.74411,0.74412,0.74346,0.74349,0.74414,0.74414,0.74344,0.74349,5713
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,6,0.74349,0.74462,0.74291,0.74299,0.74349,0.74464,0.74293,0.743,12650
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,7,0.74299,0.74363,0.74267,0.74361,0.743,0.74363,0.74269,0.74362,8067
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,8,0.74361,0.74375,0.74279,0.74287,0.74362,0.74376,0.7428,0.74288,6988
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,9,0.74287,0.74322,0.74212,0.74318,0.74288,0.74323,0.74212,0.74319,7784
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,10,0.74318,0.74329,0.74249,0.74276,0.74319,0.74331,0.7425,0.74276,5271
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,11,0.74276,0.74301,0.74179,0.74201,0.74276,0.74303,0.7418,0.74199,7434
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,12,0.74201,0.74239,0.74061,0.74064,0.74199,0.74241,0.74063,0.74066,20513
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,13,0.74064,0.74124,0.73942,0.74008,0.74066,0.74124,0.73943,0.74005,19715
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,14,0.74008,0.74014,0.73762,0.73887,0.74005,0.74013,0.73764,0.73889,21137
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,15,0.73887,0.73936,0.73823,0.73831,0.73889,0.73936,0.73824,0.73833,11186
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,16,0.73831,0.73915,0.73816,0.73908,0.73833,0.73916,0.73817,0.73908,6016
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,17,0.73908,0.73914,0.73821,0.73884,0.73908,0.73917,0.73823,0.73887,6197
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,18,0.73884,0.73885,0.73737,0.73773,0.73887,0.73887,0.73737,0.73775,6127
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,19,0.73773,0.73794,0.73721,0.73748,0.73775,0.73797,0.73724,0.73751,3614
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,20,0.73748,0.73787,0.73746,0.73767,0.73751,0.7379,0.73748,0.73773,1801
AUD/USD,2018-07-26,21,0.73767,0.73807,0.73755,0.73762,0.73773,0.73836,0.73769,0.73772,1687
```

Comment: add the desired output sample

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Done

Answer (score 2):

To assign a new column `avg_market_price` as the average:

```
df = df.assign(avg_market_price=df[['openbid', 'highbid', 'lowbid', 'closebid',
   'openask', 'highask', 'lowask', 'closeask']].mean(axis=1))
```

You then want to set the index to a datetime index by combining the date and time fields, then [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) your data to daily time periods (`1d`). Finally, use apply to get the max, min and averge values on specific columns.

```
import numpy as np

>>> (df
     .set_index(df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='h'))
     .resample('1d')
     .apply({'highask': 'max', 'lowask': 'min', 'avg_market_price': np.mean}))
            highask   lowask  avg_market_price
2018-07-24  0.74300  0.74197          0.742402
2018-07-25  0.74643  0.73922          0.742142
2018-07-26  0.74634  0.73724          0.741239
2018-07-27  0.74148  0.73701          0.739011
```